# Allow users to define a variable, and replacing with the values

Tags: python

I have a string that a user entered `s = "my name is {name} and my age is {age}"` and I am trying to have `{name}` and `{age}` replaced by other strings.

In the case of a single variable `name="bob"`, using `.replace('{name}', 'bob')` would be simple if it was only `{name}`, but I am aiming to have around 10-15 different variables, which would complicate things.

The variable could be at any position in the string, I am also getting the string from a database `d = {'name': 'bob', 'age': 18}`, so f-strings can't be used.

Comment: This is why they created [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals).

Comment: Your string will have to have ‘keys’ that they should replace, like {name} - so your database will have to store the keys because how else could you work out which variable to replace with what value?

Comment: Please give some totally specific minimal but representative example of the string you want things replaced in, *and* the information that will be stored in the database that gives you enough information to do the replacement

Comment: The information that would be stored is just the string, for example "My name is {name} and I am {age}"

Comment: And how will what to replace with what will be specified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can expand a dict into `str.format()`.

```
s = "my name is {name} and my age is {age}"
d = {'name': 'bob', 'age': 18}
print(s.format(**d))  # -> my name is bob and my age is 18
```

Related: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/4518341)